# How to make simple connection to facebook in C#?

Tags: c#, facebook

I have a windows aplication form.

I need somehow to connect to my facebook account from it and... return my name and surname (write this value to the label). That will be enough.

I was found several information about hot to do it on asp.net or MVC, but what about simple application?

Comment: Before downvoting, at least write the reason. Not everyone are so smart in this world =(

Comment: This question doesn't contain nearly enough context. Please provide an example of code you have already tried running to do this.

Comment: What kind of content do you expect If I don't even know where to start?

Comment: This really isn't the place for that kind of question then. You need to have put some effort into solving the problem yourself before expecting anyone else to be able to help you.

Comment: Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3 Then use the information from there to build what you require. If at any point in the process you have tried EVERYTHING and it does not work, then come over here back to SO and give us a shout. This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need it, but you will find there a basic connecting / extracting application.

[This is the documentation for facebook sdk for C#.](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/)